# Laravel Sending Empty/Blank View?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, swiftmailer

I'm new to laravel but I'm pretty sure I'm doing nothing wrong here: I'm trying to send an email with the following view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
  <body>
    <h2>Welcome to my site</h2>

    <div>
        Your sign up details are below:
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and code:

```
 $data = array(
      'details'=>'Your awesome detail here',
      'name'   => 'name',
      'data'   => 'daaklsdfkalfks'
    );

    $user = [
        'email' => 'amilajack@hotmail.com',
        'name' => 'amilajack'
    ];

    Mail::send('emails.test', $data, function($message) use ($user)
    {
      $message->from('info@fertona.com', 'Site Admin');
      $message->to($user['email'], $user['name'])->subject('Welcome to My Laravel app!');
    });

    return View::make('emails.test')->with('data', $data);
```

I'm not getting any errors. The email is sent BUT there is no message attached. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: they're separated. I created the view by making a file called "test.blade.php" in the views/ directory.

Answer (score 0):

You have used `emails.test` in your `Mail::send` method so it means your `view` is in `app/views/emails` and the file name is `test.blade.php`. Since you are passing following data to the view:

```
$data = array(
    'detail'=>'Your awesome detail here',
    'name'  => 'name'
);
```

So you can use something like this:

```
<h2>Welcome {{$name}}</h2>

<div>
    Your sign up details are below <br />:
    {{$details}}
</div>
```

In your `view` you didn't use any variable to output the data, it's only a static `HTML`. Since you are passing the `$user` in to your function so you may use something like this:

```
$message->to($user['email'], $user['name'])->subject('Welcome to My Laravel app!');
```

Comment: Hmm it still doesnt seem to work. I changed the code a little. I update the question

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. Turns out I was using SSL instead of TLS...very strange even though I configured the mail.php file correctly